# How do I force /web in the URL?

Tags: redirection, multi-sites

I have installed Drupal 8 as multi-site using Composer (as described by [kalose](https://www.kalose.net/oss/drupal-8-setting-multi-site/)). Basically, the folders created as subdomain-folders have been replaced with a symbolic link to the respective sub-domain folders in /sites.
I have 2 websites on 2 sub-domains, sub1.example.be/web and sub2.example.be/web.

In the public_html directory, I placed an index.php file with the following code.

```php
header ("Location: https://sub1.example.be/web");
```

It works fine.

Where can I put a similar index.php file to redirect users who use the old link (sub2.example.be) to sub2.example.be/web?
Is there any other alternative to achieve the same?

Comment: Simply point your domain to the /web subfolder.

Comment: You can use the .htaccess to redirect a specific URL https://mediatemple.net/community/products/all/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-.htaccess-file

Comment: If you are looking for an easy solution, try the Multisite Redirect module.  https://www.drupal.org/project/multisite_redirect

Comment: This helps for  subsites that have their own domain name. For the specific case of sub2, I'l just leave it like that. It has very few users and no public use.